# How to resize the scrollbar in angular?

Tags: angular

How to resize following scroll bar? Tried following options.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    //style
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    //style
}
```

[image]

Wish to resize the green color.

Comment: are the styles getting applied to the correct element? Your CSS should be correct.

Comment: Yes, it is getting applied. With following style width is getting increase but not decrease.

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 100px;
}

Comment: @cloned any suggestion?

Comment: How would I suggest anything? You barely provided any code and you also wrote you can set the width with `with: 100px` ... So what is working for you, what isn't? And what do you exactly expect to happen?

Comment: @cloned I have code where multiple cards are displayed horizontally. If the cards are 4 it goes beyond the screen and about mentioned scroll bar appears. Here I'm using angular material. Now this scrollbar thumb is automatically rendered. I wish to reduced it's size.

Comment: Add additional information to your question, not in the comments. You can edit your post. I know I repeat myself now, but you wrote that you can set the width with `width: 100px` ... Doesn't this work here? if not, why not?